# How to write a dummy network device driver

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to write a dummy network driver and have written the code, but I'm facing issue while trying to load driver i.e. it's crashing the kernel sometimes and sometimes it doesn't respond.

**Dummy device code**

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/netdevice.h>


int virtualNIC_open(struct net_device *dev) {
 printk("virtualNIC_open called\n");
 netif_start_queue(dev);
 return 0;
}

int virtualNIC_release(struct net_device *dev) {
 printk("virtualNIC_release called\n");
 netif_stop_queue(dev);
 return 0;
}

int virtualNIC_xmit(struct sk_buff *skb, struct net_device *dev) {
 printk("dummy xmit function called...\n");
 dev_kfree_skb(skb);
 return 0;
}

int virtualNIC_init(struct net_device *dev);


const struct net_device_ops my_netdev_ops = {
 .ndo_init = virtualNIC_init,
 .ndo_open = virtualNIC_open,
 .ndo_stop = virtualNIC_release,
 .ndo_start_xmit = virtualNIC_xmit,
};

int virtualNIC_init(struct net_device *dev) {
 dev->netdev_ops = &my_netdev_ops;
 printk("virtualNIC device initialized\n");
}

struct net_device virtualNIC = {
 .netdev_ops = &my_netdev_ops,
/* .netdev_ops.ndo_init: virtualNIC_init*/
};

int virtualNIC_init_module(void) {
 int result;
 strcpy(virtualNIC.name, "virtualNIC");
 if((result = register_netdev(&virtualNIC))) {
  printk("virtualNIC: Error %d initalizing card ...", result);
  return result;
 }
 return 0;
}

void virtualNIC_cleanup (void)
    {
        printk ("<0> Cleaning Up the Module\n");
        unregister_netdev (&virtualNIC);
        return;
    }
module_init(virtualNIC_init_module);
module_exit(virtualNIC_cleanup);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Please help me to figure, where I'm going wrong.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: There is already a dummy driver in the linux kernel. http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/dummy.c. You can take the reference and understand the dummy driver from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is already network dummy codec in the mainline kernel. But still if you want to write for the practice. Then I think you can proceed with your own driver as well.

I have modified some of things in your driver. I think you can give one try to it see whether you can see the dummy interface in your ifconfig or not. It is just a sample code (for the interface entry in the ifconfig) and I am not handling any kind of locking or network packet transmission or reception.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/netdevice.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/etherdevice.h>

struct net_device *virtualNIC;

int virtualNIC_open(struct net_device *dev) {
printk("virtualNIC_open called\n");
return 0;
}

int virtualNIC_release(struct net_device *dev) {
printk("virtualNIC_release called\n");
netif_stop_queue(dev);
return 0;
}

int virtualNIC_xmit(struct sk_buff *skb, struct net_device *dev) {
 printk("dummy xmit function called...\n");
 dev_kfree_skb(skb);
 return 0;
}

const struct net_device_ops my_netdev_ops = {
     .ndo_init = virtualNIC_init,
     .ndo_open = virtualNIC_open,
     .ndo_stop = virtualNIC_release,
     .ndo_start_xmit = virtualNIC_xmit,
 };

int virtualNIC_init(struct net_device *dev) {
  printk("virtualNIC device initialized\n");
  return 0;
};

static void virtual_setup(struct net_device *dev){
  dev->netdev_ops = &my_netdev_ops;
 }

 int virtualNIC_init_module(void) {
 int result;
 virtualNIC = alloc_netdev(0, "virtnC%d", virtual_setup);
 if((result = register_netdev(virtualNIC))) {
  printk("virtualNIC: Error %d initalizing card ...", result);
  return result;
 }
 return 0;
}

void virtualNIC_cleanup (void)
{
  printk ("<0> Cleaning Up the Module\n");
  unregister_netdev (virtualNIC);
 }

module_init(virtualNIC_init_module);
module_exit(virtualNIC_cleanup);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: You removed "netif_start_queue(dev);" from the virtualNIC_open for some reason - not sure how this can work. Is this code tested?

Answer (score 0):

This is very helpful, I just want to add this part of code:

```
virtualNIC = alloc_netdev (0, "virtnC%d", NET_NAME_UNKNOWN, virtual_setup);
```

this has 4 parameter in new kernel...